# How to catch exact date format from value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, format, case

In `MyTable` is column named `Values` of `NVARCHAR` datatype. Here are placed many values like:

```
Alisa
20150111
Something 12
Etc 2222
4444
01/21/2015 11:01:12 AM
etc
```

I need select all values from this column but where format is like `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM` I need to convert it to DATE (without time) `mm/dd/yyyy`

I've tried to use `ISDATE`, but It not working as I want, It converting other values to date too, like from my sample list `4444` to date format.

This is my query for now:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(Values) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Values, 101) 
            ELSE Values
       END AS Val1   
FROM MyTable
```

So list should be returned in following:

```
Alisa
20150111
Something 12
Etc 2222
4444
01/21/2015 -- this line should be changed
etc
```

Comment: `20150111` seems like a date too

Comment: That's why I need to convert only format like this: `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

Comment: You can try to use the regular expression to match the format you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to check if string contains `/` as below:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(Values) = 1 and CHARINDEX('/',Values) > 0 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Values, 101) 
            ELSE Values
       END AS Val1   
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: I've already found solution silimar to your's and It worked, I will accept It as correct answer after 7 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Values LIKE '__/__/____%' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Values, 101) 
            ELSE Values
       END AS Val1   
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: your approach is correct however the column is already in character datatype. you need to first convert it into `datetime` and then convert it back as per required format. something like this `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATE,[Values]), 101)` . +1

Answer (score 1):

This script will validate the date of the right format and take the first 10 characters if it is a date otherwise, it will pick the original value of values. Note values is a reserved word. In other situations you can use try_convert from sqlserver 2012.

```
DECLARE @t table([Values] varchar(50))

INSERT @t values ('01/20/2015 01:01:01 AM')
INSERT @t values ('02/28/2014 01:01:01 PM')
INSERT @t values ('02/35/2014 01:01:01 PM')
INSERT @t values ('4444')

SELECT 
  CASE WHEN [Values] like 
   '[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[1-2][0189][0-9][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M' 
   and isdate([Values]) = 1
    THEN 
      left( [Values], 10) -- format of date was already verified 
            ELSE [Values]
       END AS Val1   
FROM @t MyTable
```

Result:

```
Val1
01/20/2015
02/28/2014
02/35/2014 01:01:01 PM
4444
```

Answer (score 0):

if your format is exaclty `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

```
select * 
from somewhere 
where Values like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M' 
   AND ISDATE(Values) = 1
```